# Convert a list of minutes into lists of minutes, hours, days and months in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of big numbers in minutes and I would like to convert or get from this four lists of minutes, hours, days and months. Lke for example:

```
Minutes
21601
30
0
90000
```

Resulting lists:

```
Minutes  Hours  Days  Months
1        0      15    0
30       0      0     0
0        0      0     0
0        12     2     2
```

Assumptions will be that a month has exactly 30 days. Also I know i showed them here as columns for simplicity but those will be lists.
Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below method

```
def format (minutes):
    year = (int) (minutes/(12*30*24*60))
    month = ((int) (minutes/(30*24*60)))%12
    day = ((int) (minutes/(24*60)))%30
    hour = ((int) (minutes/(60)))%24
    min = ((int) (minutes))%60
    return [min,hour,day,month,year]

lis = [21601,30,0,90000]
ans = list(map(lambda x: format(x) , lis))
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing this would be to use datetime.timedelta.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = timedelta(minutes=90000)
print("DAYS:SECONDS")
print("%d:%d" % (d.days, d.seconds))
```

This gives you:

> DAYS:SECONDS 62:43200

You can always convert that to which ever date format you want

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object together with a `datetime`.

Example:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

def convert_from_minutes(minutes):
    td = timedelta(minutes=minutes)
    dt = datetime(1,1,1)
    result = dt + td
    return {
        "days": result.day-1,
        "hours": result.hour,
        "minutes": result.minute,
        "seconds": result.second
    }

ans = convert_from_minutes(21601)
ans["days"]     # gives 15
ans["hours"]    # gives 0
ans["minutes"]  # gives 1
ans["seconds"]  # gives 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the division/remainder operations into one using the builtin function [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
rem, minutes = zip(*(divmod(x, 60) for x in list_minutes))
rem, hours = zip(*(divmod(x, 24) for x in rem))
months, days = zip(*(divmod(x, 30) for x in rem))
```

Of course, you can use the `datetime.timedelta` function to get a timedelta from  your minutes, however, this would still require some extra math ops to get the months and hours.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way around, though I don't if this is the nicest way but it seems to work:

```
# list_minutes -is a list of minutes 
minutes=[x % 60 for x in list_minutes]
remeinder1=[x // 60 for x in list_minutes]
hours=[x % 24 for x in remeinder1]
remeinder2=[x // 24 for x in remeinder1]
days=[x % 30 for x in remeinder2]
month=[x % 30 for x in remeinder2]
```

Cheers.

Comment: there are definitely better ways to do this. Let us know if you're interested.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight yeah sure, I 'm definately seeing way better ways in other responses